# Xcode 11 how to use editor and assistant editor

Tags: xcode, xcode11

In Xcode 10 I used the shortcut `cmd` + `alt` to open a second editor and `cmd` + `return` to close the second one.
In Xcode 11 I can open a second editor using  `cmd` + `alt` but `cmd` + `return` is not working.
Clicking [Show Editor Only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIjTf.png) isn't working as well.

What am I missing? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look 2 menu items further down.

To open **and** close a second editor you can press <kbd>⌃⌥⌘↩</kbd>

Comment: If I use this shortcut I cant open a second editor with `cmd` + `alt`..
Isn't there a way to use the previous shortcuts?

Comment: No, there isn't because the design of the assistant editors changed completely.